# WooCommerce: Change image version in FlexSlider gallery navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gallery, flexslider

I want to change the image version used by the FlexSlider on the WooCommerce product page.
At the moment the slider uses for its gallery navigation the `thumbnail` size.
But these image size is cropped and I need an uncropped version.
There is already a size in WooCommerce which I could use: `woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail`

Unfortunately I couldn't find any hook or option to change the used image.
What I found and use is the filter `woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options`.

At the moment I'm using only one option of it:

```
$options['controlNav'] = wp_is_mobile() ? true : 'thumbnails';
```

But I see no option to change the used image version.
Is there anythin I could use/hook?

OK, I tried to use the following filter:
(https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/df94b6570df6f6002f61c9e53c8054eb77c2c405/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1499)

```
function wc_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_id, $main_image = false ) {
    $flexslider        = (bool) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', get_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' ) );
    $gallery_thumbnail = wc_get_image_size( 'gallery_thumbnail' );
    $thumbnail_size    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', array( $gallery_thumbnail['width'], $gallery_thumbnail['height'] ) );
    $image_size        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_image_size', $flexslider || $main_image ? 'woocommerce_single' : $thumbnail_size );
    $full_size         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'full' ) );
    $thumbnail_src     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $thumbnail_size );
    $full_src          = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $full_size );
    $alt_text          = trim( wp_strip_all_tags( get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ) ) );
    $image             = wp_get_attachment_image(
        $attachment_id,
        $image_size,
        false,
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params',
            array(
                'title'                   => _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_title', $attachment_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
                'data-caption'            => _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $attachment_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
                'data-src'                => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
                'data-large_image'        => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
                'data-large_image_width'  => esc_attr( $full_src[1] ),
                'data-large_image_height' => esc_attr( $full_src[2] ),
                'class'                   => esc_attr( $main_image ? 'wp-post-image' : '' ),
            ),
            $attachment_id,
            $image_size,
            $main_image
        )
    );

    return '<div data-thumb="' . esc_url( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '" data-thumb-alt="' . esc_attr( $alt_text ) . '" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="' . esc_url( $full_src[0] ) . '">' . $image . '</a></div>';
}
```

There are options for the `$gallery_thumbnail`, `$thumbnail_size` and `$thumbnail_src`.

I don't know which one ist the correct one to change the output of the gallery navigation thumbnail.

I tried the following code but I'm not sure if that code is correct (it does nothing):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', function( $thumbnail_size ) {
    return array(
        'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail',
    );
} );
```

I've read in the docs, that there are only hooks for `woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size`, `woocommerce_gallery_image_size` and `woocommerce_gallery_full_size` and they accept name based image sizes, or an array of width/height values.

So I guess the correct one would be `woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size`?!

Or is the whole approach wrong?

Comment: ok, but where can I change it to that? I found no way to do that. The name `woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail` comes from the "Regenerate thumbnails" plugin. It shows there with this name

Comment: The woocommerce filter plugin is [woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?q=woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size&unscoped_q=woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size), buy yes [woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?q=woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail&unscoped_q=woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail) exists too, sorry.

Comment: Ahh, you're not talking about the name of the size! OK, I will check if there is something possible with one of these filters

Comment: I tried to use one of the filters you linked in your comment (see my example in the question). Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution. Do you have an idea or is the whole approach wrong?

Comment: No sorry Cray …

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway for the help so far